# Customizing quarkus json logging

Tags: java, exception, logging, quarkus

I would like to exclude stacktrace from quarkus json log for specific category. (using quarkiverse logging)

I've tried multiple quarkus configurations but nothing really worked. I've also tried defining my own json provider but that is not solution i am looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello dear, can you please help us with the following information so that we can help you better - **1.** Provide us the line of code which is producing stacktrace logging which you want to be removed from the log file being generated. **2.** Also, please share the code/xml of the configuration which you have tried so far but it didn't work. **3.** How did you define your own JSON provider? Can you please share its code with us.